# Scanning Books: Organizing knowledge

Tags: scanning, ebook, document-management

I'm scanning several volumes of music theory books. Apart from creating one pdf/djvu for each book, I want to logically organize the contents, across volumes, in a searchable, collectable way. (No OCR)

*Example*: Let's say "*Big Music Theory Book*" is a series with 6 Volumes. Each volume has about a dozen chapters. A certain topic discussed in Vol 1 (say, on *Meter*), is elaborated in Vol 2. So I'd want to be able to combine these two chapters together and view.

I'd want to go through pages and **add tags/keywords/text-descriptions, manually**, to whole page or regions, and retrieve the pages by **searching**. I'd love to be able to create **topic wise views**, that retrieve pages across views. (In our example, the *Meter*)

Searching, collecting and presenting content in different views are not new to us. But,

1. is there a (collection of) software, preferably open source, for doing the same on scanned pages.
2. If not and if I have to hack around, what is the best way to start (*keep scanned pages loose; djvu with outline, hidden text; epub ...*)

Comment: You can't search a bunch of page _pictures_ without OCRing them, can you?

Comment: Well, you could index them manually, adding in page numbers and keywords that would be stored in some sort of back-end. But unless you know that your OCR software is crap for this input, you're probably better off applying OCR to the lot and storing it as hidden text and doing a search.

Comment: Some of these books are languages that OCR won't work yet. Tried some opensource ocrs on English scans, without good results. Anyways, 'Full-text' not needed. I'm ok with manually adding keywords to pages.